# How to Get total and Current Slide Number of Carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

Can you please let me know how I can get the total and current number of the carousel slides in bootstrap like the image below?

[image: Image showing current page and total number of pages]

I have an standard Bootstrap carousel and a `<div>` with the `.num` class to display the total and current number and I used this code to retrieve the numbers but it didn't go through

```
$('.num').html(){
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({number})
}
```

Thanks

**Update:**

Please find a sample at this  jsfiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/QTjET/1/)

Comment: Which carousel plugin are you using?

Comment: Hi Khawer, I am using BootStrap Carousel

Comment: You can also find a working example here :http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/QTjET/1/

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Each `slide` has a `.item` class to it, you can get the total number of slides like this

```
var totalItems = $('.item').length;
```

Active `slide` has a class named as `active`, you can get the index of `active slide` like this

```
var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
```

You can update these values by binding the bootstrap carousel `slid` event like this

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function() {
    currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
   $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');
});
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zq6gkcbo/)

Comment: I had to use ```$('#my_id').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() { ... });``` in BS v3.3.2

Comment: it's not technically correct, as the total number of `items` can be different from actual number of slides

Comment: @pauljm Yes that also works with bootstrap 4 thank you! The number didn't update with the original answer.....

Comment: I had use `var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;` for getting total number of silder in BS v5.0

Answer (score 18):

Update of @Khawer Zeshan's code
For Bootstrap 3.0+ use `slid.bs.carousel` instead of `slid` and `on` instead of `bind` . So the update code will be like that

```
var totalItems = $('.item').length;
var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
    currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
   $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var totalItemsPop = $('#Mycarousel .item').length; 
$('#Mycarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
       setTimeout(function(){ 
            currentIndexPop = $('#Mycarousel div.active').index() + 1;
            $('.num').html('' + currentIndexPop + '/' + totalItemsPop + '');
         }, 1000);
   });
```

after slide event, div will be active and can not get active index, so keep your code inside set time out function

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap 3.2+:

```
carouselData.getItemIndex(carouselData.$element.find('.item.active'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The only drawback with the below code will be that it doesn't show up till you go to next slide (triggers after each slide change).

**JS/jQuery**

```
$('#carousel-slide').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  var carouselData = $(this).data('bs.carousel');
  var currentIndex = carouselData.getActiveIndex();
  var total = carouselData.$items.length;

  var text = (currentIndex + 1) + " of " + total;
  $('#carousel-index').text(text);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="carousel-index">
  <!-- Number will be added through JS over here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 and js

```js
  var totalItems = $('.item').length;
            var currentIndex = $('div.item.active').index() + 1;

            var down_index;
            $('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');

                $(".next").click(function(){
                currentIndex_active = $('div.item.active').index() + 2;
                if (totalItems >= currentIndex_active)
                {
                    down_index= $('div.item.active').index() + 2;
                    $('.num').html(''+currentIndex_active+'/'+totalItems+'');
                }
            });

                $(".prev").click(function(){
                    down_index=down_index-1;
                if (down_index >= 1 )
                {
                    $('.num').html(''+down_index+'/'+totalItems+'');
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


 <div class="num"></div>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-wrap="false" data-interval="false">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in bootstrap 5 with angular

in html file

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>

</div>
<div class="num"></div><!-- this last line used for showing slide number -->
```

in css file

```
/** slider css start **/
.carousel-control-prev {
    margin-left: 80%;
}
.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
    margin-top: -42px;
    bottom: unset;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    background-color: #cbb06d;
    
}
.num{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
/** slider css end **/
```

in ts file

```
/**  getting slide number start */
            var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
            var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
            $('.num').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');

            $('#carouselExampleCaptions').carousel({
              interval: 2000
            });

            $('#carouselExampleCaptions').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
              currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
              $('.num').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
            });

            /** getting silde number end */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery index() function to get the current index of active element inside list of item. So the code is look like this:

```
var currentItem = $("#carousel-1 .item.active" );
var currentIndex = $('#carousel-1 .item').index(currentItem) + 1;
```