# Detect bootstrap carosual image number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Detect bootstrap carosual image number, i am not able to find any solution, please help me to get image  slide number

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade col-lg-8 col-offset-2">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/1300x500" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
               <div class="item">
                 <img src="//placehold.it/1300x500/55EE55" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
                        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get total and Current Slide Number of Carousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823571/how-to-get-total-and-current-slide-number-of-carousel)

Comment: yes, that is the correct post for me, thank you @ Ze Rubeus  :)