# Capture bootstrap carouosel item number in form

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel page showing images and the current & total number of images on the page. I've used the code from [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823571/how-to-get-total-and-current-slide-number-of-carousel) on this forum to get the image counters working, and what I would like to do next is capture the current image number in a form to pass it to a php script, so I can modify the image via php as needed.

My current code is:

```
$(window).load(function(){

var totalItems = $('.item').length;

var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
$('num').html(''+currentIndex+'');
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = "The current is: " + currentIndex;

$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;
$('num').html(''+currentIndex+'');
document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = "The current is: " + currentIndex;
});
});
```

And then:

```
<p id="dum"></p>
```

How can I modify this to capture the current image number in a html form?

Comment: you already have image number in `currentIndex`. Is the issue to set some input hidden to that value?

Comment: How do I then capture `currentIndex` in a HTML form to pass it to a php script?